# mongoDB aggregation with two kind of group count

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

If I want to figure out how much "john" paid and how many people bought $10 product in this data list

Data list:

```
[
{
 "name": "john",
 "payment": 10
},
{
 "name": "john",
 "payment": 25
},
{
 "name": "michel",
 "payment": 10
}
]
```

Should I make two requests? or Is there any method to get this at once?

Comment: @Styvane yes, I will edit.

Comment: These are two entirely different aggregation queries, so you should make two requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to use 2 separate query for achieve that

**Query 1**

```
db.p.aggregate(
{
    "$match" : {"name":"john"}
},
{    
    "$group" :
    {
        "_id" : "$name",
        "total" : {"$sum" : "$payment"}
    }
}).result
```

**Query 2:**

```
db.p.count({"payment":10})
```

Comment: thanks. but I'm looking for the method using only one query. I can't find any that kind of method. but I just wish.. someone knows that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find how much each person paid

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {
    "$group": {"_id": "$name" , "total": {"$sum": "$payment"}}
  }
)
```

You can add a match clause to find how much a specific user paid

```
{
  "$match": {"name": "John" }
}
```

And this to find who all paid same amount

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {
    "$group": {"_id": "$payment" , "people": {"$addToSet": "$name"}}
  }
)
```

Similarly you can also add a match clause here to find who all paid a specific amo0unt. If you just need the count, then use db.collection.count() instead of aggregate

Comment: I'm sorry. I think my question is too simplified. I'm using group aggregation to extract daily count sum. In this situation, I need to two kind of count.